# How can I display the Database tool in WebStorm?

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide

How can I display the Database tool in WebStorm?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the database features inside WebStorm if you have [Database Tools and SQL](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10925-database-tools-and-sql)
plugin installed in **Preferences/Settings | Plugins**.
For individual users the plugin costs $3/month or $30/year; for organizations it’s $7/month or $70/year.
Users with the active [All Products Pack](https://sales.jetbrains.com/hc/en-gb/articles/207240685-What-products-are-available-under-the-All-Products-license-)
or [DataGrip](https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/) subscriptions can use the plugin at no additional cost.

See https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2020/09/support-for-database-tools-and-sql-inside-webstorm/ for more info